# Pandas apply function with column containing list of values and list of index

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I am trying to write a code in pandas. I have 5 columns, df['all'] contains the list of values and df['ind'] contain the list indexes. I want to get only those values from df['all'] which index is available in df['ind']. For example at row 0, the df['ind'] has [1, 2] and I want to get [2, 3] in a new column df['values']. I am trying but I think I am making a mistake somewhere and unable to correct it.

```
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 2, 3], [5, 6, 5], [10, 20, 30]],index=[0, 1, 2], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
    df['all'] = df.apply(lambda x: [i for i in x], axis=1)
    e = pd.Series([[1,2],[0], [1,3]], index=[0, 1, 2])
    df = df.assign(ind=e.values)
    print(df)
    df['values'] = df['ind'].apply(lambda x: [df.at[i, 'all'] for i in x])
    print(df)
```

```
        A   B   C           all     ind
    0   0   2   3     [0, 2, 3]  [1, 2]
    1   5   6   5     [5, 6, 5]     [0]
    2  10  20  30  [10, 20, 30]  [1, 2]
```

I am not sure if I call another column in apply function this way.

Comment: The row 2 column `ind` is `[1, 3]`, but your list in column `all` is of length 3 and will return index error.

Comment: That's right. I have updated.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a function and apply:

```
def func(row):
    row['values'] = [row['all'][idx] for idx in row['ind']]
    return row
df = df.apply(func, axis = 1)
```

gives:

```
    A   B   C           all     ind    values
0   0   2   3     [0, 2, 3]  [1, 2]    [2, 3]
1   5   6   5     [5, 6, 5]     [0]       [5]
2  10  20  30  [10, 20, 30]  [1, 2]  [20, 30]
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your requirement you only need values from `'all'` with indexes in `'ind'`.
So the required output is

```
  A   B   C           all     ind    values
0   0   2   3     [0, 2, 3]  [1, 2]    [2, 3]
1   5   6   5     [5, 6, 5]     [0]       [5]
2  10  20  30  [10, 20, 30]  [1, 2]  [20, 30]
```

Now when you use `df.at(i,'all')` it actually considers ith row in 'all' column and assigns the value which gives the output

```
A   B   C           all     ind                     values
0   0   2   3     [0, 2, 3]  [1, 2]  [[5, 6, 5], [10, 20, 30]]
1   5   6   5     [5, 6, 5]     [0]                [[0, 2, 3]]
2  10  20  30  [10, 20, 30]  [1, 2]  [[5, 6, 5], [10, 20, 30]]
```

as you can see since `[5,6,6]` is at `1st row` and `[10,20,30]` is at `2nd row` value stored in corresponding to `ind : [1,2]` is `[[5, 6, 5], [10, 20, 30]]`

So you can replace

```
df['values'] = df['ind'].apply(lambda x: [df.at[i, 'all'] for i in x])
```

with

```
df['values'] = df.apply(lambda x: [x['all'][i] for i in x['ind']] , axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified `df[ind]` like this (last row 3 by 2) :

```
df
    A   B   C           all     ind
0   0   2   3     [0, 2, 3]  [1, 2]
1   5   6   5     [5, 6, 5]     [0]
2  10  20  30  [10, 20, 30]  [1, 2]
```

```py
df['values'] = [df.iloc[r, c].tolist() for r,c in list(enumerate(df['ind']))]

print(df)
```

**Result**

```
    A   B   C           all     ind    values
0   0   2   3     [0, 2, 3]  [1, 2]    [2, 3]
1   5   6   5     [5, 6, 5]     [0]       [5]
2  10  20  30  [10, 20, 30]  [1, 2]  [20, 30]
```